# Handling Push Notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications, push

I'm trying to figure out how to navigate to a stack of views when

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

is called after receiving a push notification.  My views are arranged such that I have a navigation controller with a tabcontroller.  Each of the tabs in the tab controller are navigation controllers.  I am trying to push a UIViewController on a navigation controller within a tabcontroller.  I'm able to set the proper tab, but I can't seem to do the push.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I was using the wrong navigation controller.  The solution was to get the selectedViewController from the tab controller and push straight onto that.  

   [((UINavigationController*)[tabController selectedViewController]) pushViewController:nvc animated:NO];